# Fetching data with GET request is returning 401 error while using ReactJS and Supabase as a backend

Tags: reactjs, supabase

I tried fetching data with useEffect hook but always returning error in the developer tools console, Tried to figure out why is occuring but no solution even I disabled RLS

here is the component code:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import supabase from "./../config/supabaseConfig"

export default function Home() {
    const [err, setErr] = useState(null)
    const [table, setTable] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const {data, error} = await supabase
                .from('supabases')
                .select()

                if (error) {
                    setErr('could not fetch the table')
                    setTable(null)
                }

                if (data) {
                    console.log(data)
                    setTable(data)
                    setErr(null)
                }
        }

        fetchData()
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="home-page">
            {err && (<div> {err} </div>)}
            {table && (
                <div className="table">
                    {
                        table.map(e => (
                            <p>{e.title}</p>
                        ))
                    }
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

and the supabase config file

```js
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'

const supabaseUrl = import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_SUPABASE_URL
const supabaseKey = import.meta.env.VITE_REACT_APP_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY
const supabase = createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseKey)

export default supabase
```

I tried to logout the supabase object and it works fine showing API and URL like in the website...

Comment: The code looks fine. Where is this "supabases" table created? should be in "public". Also, go to the API playground and try the same request from their UI. API Docs: on the project view -> left menu -> second item from bottom "API Docs" -> in the secondary left menu select "supabases" -> select Bash on top right -> try curl in terminal

Comment: You should be receiving an error message inside your `error` object. Console log the `error` object and let us know what exactly the error might be.